# Bittrex INVALID_MARKET_ORDER

Tags: json

I am POSTing the following data to Bittrex:

```
POST /v3/orders HTTP/1.1

Content-Type: application/json
Api-Key: xxxxxxxx
Api-Timestamp: 1609676708784
Api-Content-Hash: xxxxxxxxx
Api-Signature: xxxxxxxx

{
    "direction": "BUY",
    "marketSymbol": "CVC-BTC",
    "quantity": "5000",
    "timeInForce": "GOOD_TIL_CANCELLED",
    "type": "MARKET" 
}
```

The data is given in a shortened way for convenience.

Bittrex responds with :

`{"code":"INVALID_MARKET_ORDER"}`

I am following the API documentation at https://bittrex.github.io/api/v3#/definitions/NewOrder

Question: What is wrong in the order POSTed to Bittrex?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I found the solution.

Instead of `GOOD_TIL_CANCELLED`, use `IMMEDIATE_OR_CANCEL`, and it will work.

The documentation on https://bittrex.github.io/api/v3#/definitions/NewOrder does not mention this. The documentation at Bittrex should be updated to indicated that the field `timeInForce` is different for market or limit orders.

Comment: https://bittrexglobal.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360012450540-Order-types
You can find the related information in that guide